# Seeking Career guidance

Tags: bigdata

I am a recent graduate.Currently I work in a late stage startup (product company) as a Software Engineer where my responsibilities are to interact with customers, understand their environment and write code so that they can use our product. I work on C#, web services and relational databases. I also work rarely on Big Data space to migrate some small components of our product to big data platform. I've got an opportunity to work in a large firm as a big data engineer to work on apache projects like yarn and hadoop and solve customer issues. And also to contribute to open source community. In curreny company, there is no one to review my work and mentor me. 
Will it be a wise decision to leave a company where I've an opportunity to see product from end to end and go to a company where I'll not the same visibility of product ?

Is my next opportunity a good one if I want to make my career in big data space ?

Please share your inputs to help me take my decision ?

Comment: I think this is off topic....

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is off-topic, but I'll still try to answer because it might help you. Getting a job in data science isn't something everybody can do, it's a competitive field. Well done, for landing yourself in data science. However, data science is a big area, so you'll need to think what you want to do and plan ahead.

Do you want to get yourself into machine learning? Do you want to get yourself into statistics? Right now, you're more like a software engineer in the field, still not quite being a data scientist. Do you want to become a real data scientist? Or are you happy being a software engineer in the field? If you're planning to become a data scientist, you should train yourself hard in statistics, machine learning etc. Being a Hadoop user is simply not enough to step yourself fully into the field.

I give you my own experience. I was a software engineer myself. It wasn't easy to get a job in data science. I had to do a postgraduate degree in mathematics. Trained myself as much as possible. In the end, I landed myself a job as a bioinformatician.

**Recommendation**

Don't leave just because nobody mentors you. Learn as much as possible and prepare yourself. Once you're comfortable, move on.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this short free eBook might give you some insights on what to do:

[Analyzing the Analyzers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029014.do)

Comment: I found [this](https://www.boozallen.com/media/file/The-Field-Guide-to-Data-Science.pdf) a lot helpful when I was starting to learn about the domain :)

Answer (score 0):

I am voting to close it as off-topic.  (StudentT has already given a wonderful answer :) )

Firstly, it is up to you to take the decision.

You have to have a passion for data, and willing to get your feet dirty at it.

It is not the end, if your colleagues are not mentoring you. No one mentored me when I was preparing myself. I have written [an answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-mentors-to-guide-me-to-become-a-data-scientist-at-Facebook-Google-or-LinkedIn/answer/Jalem-Raj-Rohit) about how I disturbed a lot of people till they mentored me. In fact, they were very happy to.

> Will it be a wise decision to leave a company where I've an
>   opportunity to see product from end to end and go to a company where
>   I'll not the same visibility of product ?

The domain of data science is very difficult. Let me cite an example from my team.  Me, being the lead, have an idea of the entire product end-to-end, however the ones in my team working on customer success analytics don't have the complete idea on the entire product(in fact, they don't need to), and vice versa.  So, it is completely dependant on the role.

> Is my next opportunity a good one if I want to make my career in big
>   data space ?

Big data space?  **Yes**  In data science? Maybe, but you have a [lot of ground to 
cover](http://nirvacana.com/thoughts/becoming-a-data-scientist/).