# From developper to data scientist

Tags: beginner, books

I code a lot for web, games and some basic ML scripts. Now I would like to learn about data science.

[This post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/11172/21881) is a good starting point but I would like some readings. I would like advices on books for a beginner (maths, tools, whatever).

I've found these ones from O'Reilly :

- Machine Learning for Hackers, *By Drew Conway, John Myles White*
- Agile Data Science, *By Russell Jurney*
- R Cookbook, *By Paul Teetor*

(Sorry, my reputation is too low to let me post more than 1 link haha)

Do you recommand these readings ? Are there other must-reading books ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest [this guide](https://github.com/open-source-society/data-science) for a good introduction to the resources available to you to learn to do data science. You are starting at a good time, there are loads of excellent (and mostly free) resources to teach you this interesting field.